# Error: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method. Google API: build('admin', 'directory_v1', http=http)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, google-oauth, google-workspace

**GOAL:**
List users in Google GSuite from GAE Standard python application using a service account
**USING:**
GAE Standard, Python , GSuite
**STEPS PERFORMED:**
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation
0. All steps list in this link 1.Created Service account, 2. enabled DoD OAuth 2.0 client ID 3. In gSuite security Enable API access 4. In gSuite Manage API client access added Authorized API clients & Scope
**CODE:**

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials  
import httplib2  
from googleapiclient import discovery  
import oauth2client

def main():  

    """Shows basic usage of the Google Admin SDK Directory API. Creates a Google Admin SDK API service object and outputs a list of first 10 users in the domain."""  
    credentials =  ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(‘keys/key.json', 
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user'])

    credentials = credentials.create_delegated(‘gsuite.admin.email@domian.com’)
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('admin', 'directory_v1', http=http)

    print('Getting the first 10 users in the domain')
    results = service.users().list(customer='my_customer', orderBy='email').execute()
```

**ERROR:**

```
HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: unauthorized_client: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method.
```

Thank you, appreciate any examples that work.

**SOLUTION/ISSUE RESOLUTION**

Make sure you have the **EXACT SCOPE** in the gSuite Manage API client access Authorized API clients & Scope, had 20+ scopes in my but somehow did not have this one.

Comment: You should add an answer to your own question instead of editing it in the question - to not leave it appear unanswered. And in a couple of days or so you'll be able to mark the answer as accepted (and gain some rep as a side effect).